# MessageBoxButton exception WPF, VB.net project

Tags: wpf, vb.net, exception, messagebox

```
I am using the following code in a Button_Click event:
```

```
        If OwordDoc IsNot Nothing Then
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("A document is already open.", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information)
            Return
        End IF
```

I am getting the following runtime error no matter which MessageBoxButton enumeration I use.

```
(InvalidEnumArgumentException: 'The value of argument 'button' (64) is invalid for Enum type 'MessageBoxButton'.)
```

I'm not using any other MessageBox elsewhere.  Although this is a first time wpf project, this seems so fundamental, what am I doing wrong?

I have checked through previous StackOverflow Q/A and feel I am almost married to Microsoft Copilot!

Comment: You obviously haven't bothered to read the relevant documentation because, if you had, the problem and it's solution would be obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had read the [relevant documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.windows.messagebox.show?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), as you should have before posting a question, then you'd know that there is no overload of `MessageBox.Show` with three parameters of those types. If you'd simply paid attention to Intellisense when typing the code then you'd know too. You need to provide two `Strings` - the title and the message - followed by a `MessageBoxButton` and then a `MessageBoxImage`. In your code, the `MessageBoxButton` value is being converted to a `String` and the `MessageBoxImage` value is being converted to a `MessageBoxButton` value. As the error message clearly states, that conversion is not valid.

This is a perfect example of why you should ALWAYS have `Option Strict On`. If you had done then implicit conversions like that would not be allowed and your code would not compile. Turn `Option Strict On` in the project properties and fix any late binding or implicit conversion errors that result. You should also turn it `On` in the VB options, so it will be `On` by default for all future projects.

Comment: With many thanks jmcilhinney.  Your rebuke and advice gratefully accepted.  Clearly fundamental including my own conduct after a layoff from coding.

Comment: @barryleajo, we all make mistakes and if no one points them out, we're likely to repeat them. Glad you took it in the spirit it was intended. Many don't, and probably do repeat their mistakes as a result.